# Convert multiple binary columns into factors with names based on column name in R elegantly with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to convert a dataframe of binary variables into factors, based on the column name with specific column ordering (for facet plotting, modelling, etc later). I've got a crude, but working function which I'm now trying to convert into a dplyr pipe.

Working function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~A, ~B, ~C,
  "X", 1, 0, 0,
  "Y", 0, 0, 1,
  "Z", 1, 1, 1
)

df1 = df
for (name in c("A", "B", "C")) {
  df1[[name]] = factor(df1[[name]], levels = c(0, 1), labels = paste0(c("not ", ""), name))
}
df1$A
#> [1] A     not A A    
#> Levels: not A A
```

First attempt with dplyr. Almost, but I wanted `Levels: not A A`

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
  mutate(value = factor(if_else(value == 1, name, paste("not", name)))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% 
  droplevels()
df2$A
#> [1] A     not A A    
#> Levels: A not A  # Levels incorrect
```

Second attempt with dplyr. A

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(A:C, function(x) factor(x, levels = c(0, 1))))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   id    A     B     C    
#>   <chr> <fct> <fct> <fct>
#> 1 X     1     0     0    
#> 2 Y     0     0     1    
#> 3 Z     1     1     1
# Unable to set custom factor labels
```

Is there a way to elegantly achieve what I'm after using dplyr/tidyverse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `cur_column()` to get name of the column.

```
library(dplyr) #dplyr > 1.0.0

df1 <- df %>% 
         mutate(across(A:C, function(x) 
               factor(x, c(0, 1), paste0(c("not ", ""), cur_column()))))
df1

#  id    A     B     C    
#  <chr> <fct> <fct> <fct>
#1 X     A     not B not C
#2 Y     not A not B C    
#3 Z     A     B     C    

df1$A
#[1] A     not A A    
#Levels: not A A
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you that was exactly what I was after! Never used or seen `cur_` functions in `dplyr` so didn't know they existed. Will definitely be using them in the future